# How do I make an item that gives potion effects when held?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a clock where if it is held, you turn invisible.  I know it has something to do with tags and whatnot, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.  Everything I try fails.

I am in Minecraft 1.15.2.

Comment: "Everything [you] try fails". Like what?

Answer (score 1):

### For only curtain clocks make you invisible:

Put into an active repeating command block:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:clock",Count:1b,tag:{makesYouInvisible:1b}}}] at @s run effect give @s minecraft:invisibility 2 0 true
```

To give yourself the clock that will make you invisible:

```
/give @p minecraft:clock{makesYouInvisible:1b} 1
```

### For every clock make you invisible:

Put into an active repeating command block:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:clock"}}] at @s run effect give @s minecraft:invisibility 2 0 true
```

Comment: You don't need `/execute` here; `/effect give @a[nbt=...] minecraft:invisibility 2 0 true` works just as well.